# Inactive TCP Sockets disconnecting in Docker for Windows WSL 2

Tags: docker, sockets, wsl-2

I am observing that a TCP socket, when initiated from a Docker container (Windows host, running WSL 2, AMD64 architecture), connected to a server running on the same host will disconnect after about 6 minutes of inactivity.  Why does this happen and is there any way to prevent it or fix it?

#### Details

I originally discovered this while writing a Node.js client and server pair of applications.  The client and server application were on the same physical machine.  Originally both were Dockerized, but I found that the server-side didn't matter, and I could run the server natively on the host and still reproduce the problem.  `Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350` I created a [full repro here, which you can ignore though](https://github.com/wyckster/conntest/issues/2) because to my surprise, I can also reproduce it with **no code of my own**.

##### Steps to Reproduce

Docker (using WSL 2) is installed on the machine.

In this repro, the server app is running natively (bare metal) in Windows on the host, but the client is running in a Docker container.

In Windows, on the host, I start up an echo server.  You can use [PavelBansky/EchoTool](https://github.com/PavelBansky/EchoTool), but it doesn't matter--any TCP socket server will do.  In this case I started an echo server with:

```
echotool /p tcp /s 8002
```

Then I run a Docker container (e.g. `ubuntu`) and install telnet, and then telnet to the echo server running on the host.

```
C:\> docker run --rm -it ubuntu
root@67d6d6f9cced:/# apt update && apt-get install telnet -y
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
...
root@67d6d6f9cced:/# telnet
telnet> o 10.0.0.123 8002
Trying 10.0.0.123...
Connected to 10.0.0.123.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

##### Expected Results

I expect the client to connect to the server and stay connected indefinitely, without being disconnected.  I am able to reproduce the expected results if WSL 2 is not involved:

- By running the client directly on the host (not in Docker).
- By running the client in Docker on another platform or architecture (e.g., ARM Linux).

In the non-WSL 2 scenario, the expected results can also be achieved:

- Using different server applications.
- Using different client applications.

##### Actual Results

The client gets disconnected from the server after a period of roughly 6 minutes.

**client**

```
telnet> o 10.0.0.123 8002
Trying 10.0.0.123...
Connected to 10.0.0.123.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

**server**

```
Waiting for TCP connection on port 8002. Press any key to exit.

Client 10.0.0.123:51656 accepted at 11:21:43 AM

Session closed by peer.
Waiting for TCP connection on port 8002. Press any key to exit.
```

I can only reproduce this when the client is connected from a Docker container hosted on Windows using WSL 2.  But in that scenario, it reproduces 100% of the time.  All versions of Windows I've tried are reproducing this:  e.g.:  `Version 20H2 (OS Build 19042.1110)`, `Version 21H1 (OS Build 19043.985)`.  This happens on a variety of different physical systems with different kinds of network adapters.

##### More Info

I also noticed that if I connect *multiple* clients (from multiple Docker containers), then after about 6 minutes of inactivity, **all** clients will be disconnected *simultaneously*.  In other words, it's not that each connection is being dropped after 6 minutes of its own inactivity, in which case I would have expect staggered disconnections, it's that after about 6 minutes of inactivity **all** inactive connections are disconnected together.

If a new connection is formed immediately after disconnecting, then the period is extremely consistent: About 6 minutes and 30 seconds.

---

To me, this seems to be related to WSL 2 networking. And I'm speculating that, for some reason, WSL 2 networking is dropping inactive connections.  It is my understanding that sockets can remain connected indefinitely.  If they can't, then why can I perform this test and observe indefinite connections on all other platforms except WSL 2?  Could it be a bug?  Why are inactive sockets being disconnected when using WSL 2?  How can I fix or prevent this?

Comment: I have seen a similar problem using a django client inside docker connecting to a postgres server running on the windows host. This disconnect also happens on the mac, so I think it is a docker problem not a WSL2 problem. The docker issue https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2406 seems related, but that is supposedly fixed.

Comment: @sknutsonsf, agreed.  If I just install an ubuntu distro in WSL 2 and open a telnet from there, the connection can remain open indefinitely.  Docker must be involved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

Looks like the MTU of the WSL Ubuntu interface between docker and the host is lower than 1500.

I changed my MTU settings in the docker settings and in my docker compose yaml and have not had a drop since.

```
networks:
    backend:
      driver: bridge
      driver_opts:
        com.docker.network.driver.mtu: 1400
```

credits:

https://mlohr.com/docker-mtu/

https://sylwit.medium.com/how-we-spent-a-full-day-figuring-out-a-mtu-issue-with-docker-4d81fdfe2caf

EDIT:
I didn't realize in my testing that I also had the following configuration in my docker compose yaml file which is required to fix the timeout issue:

```
sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=200
```

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling to find out why socket disconnects after 5 mins everytime.
I finally find out the answer.
Answer is :

> **Port Idle time**

[Docker Desktop now has](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/) `vpnKitMaxPortIdleTime` parameter in `%APPDATA%\Docker\settings.json`.

I change `vpnKitMaxPortIdleTime`'s value from 300 to 0 (default: 300)
after that, the problem is solved.